# Platform to manage and analyze peer evaluations?

Tags: database-recommendation

Our academic department (at a US university) collects mandatory paper-based peer evaluations at undergraduate level for a number of classes each semester. So in a typical class of 60 students, folks must complete a final project in teams. They would form 10-15 teams of 4-5 people each. By the end of semester, each team member is required to rate every member of their team including him/herself and add any written feedback. To avoid free-riding, this information goes into the final grade calculation.

We are now looking for ways to ditch paper-based evaluations for good and make all peer submissions electronic. It seem simple but online survey providers cannot give us what we need due to very limited capabilities of their platforms. For example, Qualtrics (that **is** designed to build and analyze surveys) can only allow typing each respondent name manually or coping and pasting several rows of data. Imagine having 60 students per class, 8 classes each semester? Typing those names will not only take forever but also create many typos and misspellings due to human error. (Excel spreadsheets can still be imported into Qualtrics but for different purposes. Qualtrics has an array of other technical issues.)

We want to be able to upload a spreadsheet with all registered students and their team memberships into a specific survey design, so that by choosing their team from a dropdown menu on the first page, a respondent will see a list of all their team members on the next page. Are you aware of any online source that can help us do that?

I will greatly appreciate any feedback from you.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds more like you need a Survey application and not a survey database. Did you have a look at Survey Monkey? It allows import of Excel data.

Comment: The roster upload functionality of MyClassEvaluation from http://iotasolutions.com is designed to do just that. Disclaimer: I work for IOTA Solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. We are currently exploring MyClassEvaluation service.'